# DataGridView Data Population

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to populate my datagridview. The scenario is as follows: In my sql server management studio i have created a new view from join that is joining 3 of my tables into one view. Now in my c# program i have a form on which there are two things. One is the datetime picker and the other is the datagridview. Now when i simply provide the datasource as that view i made in the sql management studio, the datagridview is populated fine. However, what am trying to do is add a query to that datagridview in which i want to supply the value from the datetimepicker control. am confused how to achieve this, kindly guide me how to accomplish this:
Following is the query i tried to execute in add query to my datagridview option: but it is not working:

```
SELECT cnic, 
       name, 
       comp_name, 
       date_in, 
       date_out, 
       time_in, 
       time_out, 
       chk_in, 
       chk_out 
FROM dbo.visitor_status

WHERE dbo.visitor_status.date_in = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

AND (dbo.visitor_status.chk_in = 1 and dbo.visitor_status.chk_out = 0)
```

Comment: whats the data type of visitor_status.date_in column?

Comment: date is the data type of date_in column in sql server!

Comment: please post some code where you set the datasource to datagridview.

Comment: they are images and i dnt have enuf reputation here to post them. Its like this. I click on the arrow on the side of datagridview select datasource provide my database and then select the table to bind with the datagridview. Now i click on arrow again to add a query, and specify the above query there!